# Why is a class scope variable captured when using an async method but not when using an Action<T> (code examples inside)?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

While walking the dog I was thinking about `Action<T>`, `Func<T>`, `Task<T>`, `async/await` (yes, nerdy, I know...) and constructed a little test program in my mind and wondered what the answer would be. I noticed I was unsure about the result, so I created two simple tests.

Here's the setup:

- I have a class scope variable (string).
- It gets assigned an initial value.
- The variable is passed as a parameter to a class method.
- The method won't be executed directly, but instead is assigned to an 'Action'.
- Before the action executes, I change the value of the variable.

**What would the output be? The initial value, or the changed value?**

A little surprising but understandable, the output is the changed value. My explanation: the variable is not pushed onto the stack until the action executes, so it will be the changed one.

```
public class foo
{
    string token;

    public foo ()
    {
        this.token = "Initial Value";
    }

    void DoIt(string someString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeString is '{0}'", someString);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Action op = () => DoIt(this.token);
        this.token = "Changed value";
        // Will output  "Changed value".
        op();
    }
}
```

Next, I created a variation:

```
public class foo
{
    string token;

    public foo ()
    {
        this.token = "Initial Value";
    }

    Task DoIt(string someString)
    {
        // Delay(0) is just there to try if timing is the issue here - can also try Delay(1000) or whatever.
        return Task.Delay(0).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("SomeString is '{0}'", someString));
    }

    async Task Execute(Func<Task> op)
    {
        await op();
    }

    public async void Run()
    {
        var op = DoIt(this.token);
        this.token = "Changed value";
        // The output will be "Initial Value"!
        await Execute(() => op);
    }
}
```

Here I made `DoIt()` return a `Task`. `op` is now a `Task` and no longer an `Action`. The `Execute()` method awaits the task. To my surprise, the output is now "Initial Value".

**Why does it behave differently?**

`DoIt()` won't be executed until `Execute()` gets called, so why does it capture the initial value of `token`?

Complete tests: https://gist.github.com/Krumelur/c20cb3d3b4c44134311f and https://gist.github.com/Krumelur/3f93afb50b02fba6a7c8

Comment: In DoIt, the capture is on someString, the method parameter, not on the token field. As the value you pass to the method is 'Initial value' that's the value you see.

Comment: *DoIt() won't be executed until Execute() gets called* - not true. When you instantiate a task in an `async` context it is started immediately - it doesn't wait until it's `await`ed (so you can await multiple concurrent tasks).

Comment: @AntP That's of course right - and I know this. Seems I was so baffled by the different behavior that I forgot about it. :-) Looking at the upvotes, the question seems to draw quite some interest.

Comment: @Krumelur it is an interesting question but actually the whole `Task` vs `Action` thing is a red herring:  the ultimate cause is a simple matter of string immutability!

Comment: All it'd take is stepping through the code in the debugger to see what's happening line by line to see what's going on.

Comment: @Servy the debugger is not always the answer. There are situations where optimizations in release builds will lead to different behavior.

Comment: @Krumelur Everything relevant about both of these examples is deterministic.  There aren't race conditions here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a couple of misconceptions here. Firstly, when you call `DoIt`, it  returns a Task that has already begun execution. Execution *doesn't* start only when you `await` the Task.

You also create a closure over the `someString` variable, the value of which *does not change* when you reassign the class-level field:

```
Task DoIt(string someString)
{
    return Task.Delay(0).ContinueWith(t 
        => Console.WriteLine("SomeString is '{0}'", someString));
}
```

The `Action` passed to `ContinueWith` closes on the `someString` variable. Remember that strings are *immutable* so, when you reassign the value of `token`, you are actually assigning a *new string reference*. The local variable `someString` inside `DoIt`, however, retains the old reference, so its value remains the same even after the class field is reassigned.

You could solve this problem by instead having this action close over the class-level field directly:

```
Task DoIt()
{
    return Task.Delay(0).ContinueWith(t 
        => Console.WriteLine("SomeString is '{0}'", this.token));
}
```

Comment: Instantiating tasks has the same behaviour in and out of `async` methods. There's a few differences between `async` and non-`async` methods, but this isn't one of them. If you call `Task.Delay` in a non-`async` method, it will still start executing right away.

Answer (score 6):

In both cases, you are making a closure. However, you're making a closure over different things in the two cases.

In the first case, you're making an anonymous method with a closure over `this` - when you finally execute the delegate, it will take the *current* value of `this`, get the *current* value of `this.token` and use that. So you see the modified value.

In the second case, there is no closure over `this` - or if it is, it doesn't make a difference. You pass `this.token` explicitly, and the `DoIt` method only needs to make a closure over its own argument, `someString`. This happens immediately (synchronously), rather than lazily - so the initial value of `this.token` is captured. `await` doesn't actually *execute* the delegate - it only waits for the results of the asynchronous method. The method itself has already ran, and only it's asynchronous part is, well, asynchronous - in this case, only the `Console.WriteLine("SomeString is '{0}'", someString)`.

If you want to see this more clearly, add `Thread.Sleep(1000)` after `this.token = "Changed value";` - you will see `SomeString is 'Initial Value'` printed out *before* you even get to the `await`.

To make the second example behave like the first, all you need to do is change `op` to be a delegate again, rather than a `Task` - `var op = () => DoIt(this.token);`. This delays execution of `DoIt` again, and causes the same closure as in the first example.

TL;DR:

The behaviour is different because in the first case, you defer the execution of `DoIt(this.token)`, while in the second example you run `DoIt(this.token)` immediately. The other points in my answer are also important, but this is the crux.

Answer (score 6):

Let's break down each case.

Starting with the `Action<T>`:

> My explanation: the variable is not pushed onto the stack until the
>   action executes, so it will be the changed one

This hasn't anything to do with the stack. The compiler generates the following from your first code snippet:

```
public foo()
{
    this.token = "Initial Value";
}

private void DoIt(string someString)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SomeString is '{0}'", someString);
}

public void Run()
{
    Action action = new Action(this.<Run>b__3_0);
    this.token = "Changed value";
    action();
}

[CompilerGenerated]
private void <Run>b__3_0()
{
    this.DoIt(this.token);
}
```

The compiler emits a named method from your lambda expression. Once you invoke the action, and since we're in the same class, the `this.token` is the updated "Changed Value". The compiler doesn't even lift this into a display class, since this is all created and invoked inside the instance method.

---

Now, for the `async` method. There are two state-machines being generated, ill skimp the bloat of the state-machine and get to the relevant parts. The state-machine does the following:

```
this.<>8__1 = new foo.<>c__DisplayClass4_0();
this.<>8__1.op = this.<>4__this.DoIt(this.<>4__this.token);
this.<>4__this.token = "Changed value";
taskAwaiter = this.<>4__this.Execute(new Func<Task>(this.<>8__1.<Run>b__0)).GetAwaiter();
```

What happens here? `token` is passed to `DoIt`, which will return a `Func<Task>`. That delegate contains a reference to the old token string, "Initial Value". Remember, even though we're talking about reference types, they are all passed by value. This effectively means that there is a new storage location for the old string now in the `DoIt` method which points to "Initial Value". Then, the next line changes `token` to "Changed Value". The `string` stored inside the `Func` and the one that was changed are **now pointing at two different strings**.

When you invoke the delegate, it will print the initial value, as the `op` task stores your older, stale value. That is why you're seeing two different behaviors.

Comment: "now pointing at two different strings" - that's what @AntP also pointed out. It is just obscured by all the surrounding code. Thanks for showing the IL version!

Comment: @Krumelur I wanted to show you what actually happens. This isn't IL, this is simply the decompiled code :)

Comment: True. I wrote "IL" because I was wondering what you used to decompile and thought, maybe it was "**IL** Spy" :-)

Comment: @Krumelur ILSpy. Love that tool :)